# What is the purpose of "Package Cache" registry entries?

Tags: delphi, registry, package

What are "cached" packages?

May I delete entries in this registry branch, without causing trouble for my Delphi projects?

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to discover why my Delphi IDE takes too long to open. I know it is related to our componentes, it starts to slow down when the IDE starts to load then. Using procmon, I saw that the IDE reads the Package Cache registry and it tries to find an Report and DetailedReport keys in there, and does not find it. I saw [this](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/demandloaded-component-packages-in-delphi-2005-1833) where it says:

> You can also enable reporting globally by going to
>   HKCUSoftwareBorlandBDS3.0Package Cache and adding one or both of the
>   following values:  Report=1 or DetailedReport=1.  They correspond to
>   EnableDemandLoadReport(False) and EnableDemandLoadReport(True),
>   respectively.  The cool thing is that you can enable reporting in this
>   manner and see detailed reports for *all* design-time packages that
>   the IDE loads, including all the Borland supplied packages.

In theory, when DetailedReport is enabled, it should create a report file, with .rpt extension, when the IDE load the component, describing why it was disqualified to *lazy load*. Perhaps this does not work in Delphi Tokyo, since the post it from Delphi 2005, but even so the IDE read this registry.

[image: procmon]

This keys does not exist by default, I created it. Before, procmon showed NAME NOT FOUND in Result column.

Answer (score 0):

At best - it would be re-created as you start Delphi IDE next time.

At worst - 3rd-party components would work no more.

http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2012/08/ide-fix-pack-5-0-released/

Comment: But what are cached packages?

Comment: I do not know what precisely this cache is, however deleting the "Package Cache" and the "Palette" keys and starting IDE again, they are re-created.  Am trying to implement installing the packages through registry sort of tool, and will probably be adding the Cache delete to it .. working with 10.2 and 10.4 atm